# Convert Java Gregorian Calendar in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, datetime, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I have a JSP page with a java variable inside it which name is `${entry.date}`, type of this variable is `Gregorian Calendar` and it places in a loop and generates a table of error log at last. now my question is that is it possible in my current page, by use of `javascript`, I get the variable and converted to `Solar Calendar` object and placed it again in a my html?

**The output of `${entry.date}` is:**

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1361788629000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+03:30",offset=12600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=9,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=25,DAY_OF_YEAR=56,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=2,HOUR_OF_DAY=14,MINUTE=7,SECOND=9,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=12600000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

**And the HTML Block is:**

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${errorLog}">
<tr>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap">
        <mytag:format dateTime="${entry.date}"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Where does `<mytag:format>` comes from? And why do you want to do this in Javascript rather than in Java?

Comment: I just wanna change the view section not the original date in core java and <mytag> is a defined taglib in project, it has getDate() method but when I either changed it and convert the date there, nothing change.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do it in Javascript.  Just use the standard JSTL `formatDate` tag along with `Calendar`'s `getTime()` accessor:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
...
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${errorLog}">
<tr>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap">
        <fmt:formatDate value="${entry.date.time}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a" />
    </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

You can adjust the `pattern` to suit your needs.

**Edit:** The most elegant way to achieve what you want would be to implement the conversion/formatting in a custom tag, but another way would be:

```
<c:set var="calendar" value="${entry.date}" />
<c:set var="convertedCalendar" value='<%=SomeHelperClass.convertCalendar((Calendar)pageContext.findAttribute("calendar")) %>' />
```

where `SomeHelperClass.convertCalendar()` is some static utility method to convert your `Calendar`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but Pattern is not my problem, I want to convert Date Value, I mean Gregorian To Solar Calendar.

Comment: Alright, you may want to consider revising your question.  It's definitely not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: as a matter of fact, no dude! cos I could not do changes in java. my question is about converting date in javascript and only on view section I mean my jsp page not other places.

Comment: @MattStone In one of your comments to the question you mention trying to convert the date in the taglib code, which would imply that you have access to the Java.

Comment: yes you are right, I said that to answer Etienne Miret question, but my main question is clear on the post. why dont you consider that? :(

Comment: @Matt Stone The question isn't that clear, IMO. And besides that, a large percentage of the time when someone wants a solution that goes against best practices, they don't even realize that there's a better way to do it.  Can you answer *why* it is that the actual conversion between the calendars can't be done in a taglib or in a static method?

Comment: I tried to convert the date in taglib but I couldnt, cos I havent enough knowledge. I am a client side developer and I only can change the front end (view section) and in this time of project there is no one who can help. So I decide by using javascript in jsp page get the calendar and convert it (I know how) then display it. Thats it.